# Estou tendo problemas para salvar os dados de um input em uma tabela mysql via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, pdo

Estou tentando entender o motivo de estar dando erro no momento em que vou salvar os dados inseridos nos `input` em uma tabela mysql via PHP? alguém sabe resolver?

```
<?php
    require_once '_classes/user_login.php';
    $u = new User;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Inputs de usuario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        <h1>Cadastrar</h1>

        <form method="POST">

            <input type="" name="nNameUser" placeholder="Nome">
            <input type="" name="nEmail" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="" name="nSex" placeholder="Sexo"> <!--colocar opção por icones -Masculino/-Feminino-->
            <input type="" name="nCivilState" placeholder="Estado civil">
            <input type="" name="nBirthday" placeholder="Data nascimento">
            <input type="" name="nAlreadyJob" placeholder="Empregado atualmente?"> <!--//colocar opção por icones -Sim/-Não-->
            <input type="" name="nTelephone" placeholder="Telefone">
            <input type="" name="nMobile" placeholder="Celular">
            <input type="" name="nComercial" placeholder="Telefone comercial">
            <input type="" name="nPageHome" placeholder="Homepage">
            <input type="" name="nOringins" placeholder="Nacionalidade">
            <input type="" name="nCep" placeholder="Cep">
            <input type="" name="nAdress" placeholder="Endereço">
            <input type="" name="nHouseNumber" placeholder="Numero da casa">
            <input type="" name="nComplement" placeholder="Complemento">
            <input type="" name="nNighborhood" placeholder="Bairro">
            <input type="" name="nState" placeholder="Estado">
            <input type="" name="nCity" placeholder="Cidade">
            <input type="password" name="nPassword" placeholder="Senha">
            <input type="password" name="nConf" placeholder="Confirmar Senha">
            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
        </form>

    </div>  

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST["nNameUser"]))
        {
            $nome=addslashes($_POST["nNameUser"]);
            $email=addslashes($_POST["nEmail"]);
            $sexo=addslashes($_POST["nSex"]);
            $estado_civil=addslashes($_POST["nCivilState"]);
            $data_nascimento=addslashes($_POST["nBirthday"]);
            $empregado_atualmente=addslashes($_POST["nAlreadyJob"]);
            $telefone=addslashes($_POST["nTelephone"]);
            $celular=addslashes(isset($_POST["nMobile"])?$_POST["nMobile"]: 0);
            $telefone_comercial=addslashes(isset($_POST["nComercial"])?$_POST["nComercial"]: 0);
            $homepage=addslashes($_POST["nPageHome"]);
            $nacionalidade=addslashes($_POST["nOringins"]);
            $cep=addslashes($_POST["nCep"]);
            $endereço=addslashes($_POST["nAdress"]);
            $num_casa=addslashes($_POST["nHouseNumber"]);
            $complemento=addslashes($_POST["nComplement"]);
            $bairro=addslashes($_POST["nNighborhood"]);
            $estado=addslashes($_POST["nState"]);
            $cidade=addslashes($_POST["nCity"]);
            $senha=addslashes($_POST["nPassword"]);
            $confSenha=addslashes($_POST["nConf"]);

        }

        if(!empty($nome) && !empty($email) && !empty($sexo) && !empty($estado_civil) && !empty($data_nascimento) && !empty($empregado_atualmente) && !empty($telefone) && !empty($homepage) && !empty($nacionalidade) && !empty($cep) && !empty($endereço) && !empty($num_casa) && !empty($complemento) && !empty($bairro) && !empty($estado) && !empty($cidade) && !empty($senha) && !empty($confSenha))

        {
            $u->conect("dados_pessoais", "localhost", "root", "");

            if($u->msgError="")
            {
                if($senha == $confSenha){
                    if($u->register($nome, $email, $sexo, $estado_civil, $data_nascimento, $empregado_atualmente, $telefone, $telefone, $celular, $telefone_comercial, $homepage, $nacionalidade, $cep, $endereço, $num_casa, $complemento, $bairro, $estado, $cidade, $senha))
                    {
                        ?>
                            <div  id="msg-sucesso">
                                Dados inseridos com sucesso! Para acessar a sua área <strong><a href="#">Clique aqui!</a></strong>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ?>
                            <div class="msg-erro">
                                Email já cadastrado!
                            </div>
                        <?php
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    ?>
                        <div class="msg-erro">
                            Senhas não correspondem!
                        </div>
                    <?php
                }

            }
            else
            {
                ?>
                    <div class="msg-erro">
                        <?php
                            echo "ERRO: ".$u->msgError;
                        ?>
                    </div>
                <?php
            }

        }
        else
        {
            ?>
                <div class="msg-erro">
                    Preencha todos os campos!
                </div>
            <?php
        }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

```php
<?php

    class User{

        private $pdo;
        public $msg;

        public function conect($name, $host, $user, $password)
        {
            global $pdo;
            global $msg;

            try 
            {
                $pdo= new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$name.";host=".$host,$user, $password);
            } 
            catch (PDOException $e) 
            {
                $msgError = $e->getMessage();
            }


        }

        public function register($nome, $email, $sexo, $estado_civil, $data_nascimento, $empregado_atualmente,
         $telefone, $celular, $telefone_comercial, $homepage, $nacionalidade, $cep, $endereço, $num_casa, $complemento, $bairro, $estado, $cidade)
        {
            global $pdo;

            //Verificar se o email já existe
            $sql=$pdo->prepare("SELECT id_usuario FROM dados_pessoais WHERE email = :e");
            $sql->bindValue(":e", $email);
            $sql->execute();

            if($sql->rowsCount() > 0){
                return false; //email já cadastrado
            }
            else
            {
                //caso o email estiver cadastrado todos os dados serão salvos
                $sql=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO dados_pessoais (nome, email, sexo, estado_civil, data_nascimento, empregado_atualmente, telefone, celular, telefone_comercial, homepage, nacionalidade, cep, endereço, num_casa, complemento, bairro, estado, cidade, senha,) VALUES (:n, :e, :sx, :ec, :dn, :ea, :tr, :cl, :tc, :hp, :na, :cp, :en, :nc, :cm, :br, :et, :ct, :se)");
                $sql->bindValue(":n", $nome);
                $sql->bindValue(":e", $email);
                $sql->bindValue(":sx", $sexo);
                $sql->bindValue(":ec", $estado_civil);
                $sql->bindValue(":dn", $data_nascimento);
                $sql->bindValue(":ea", $empregado_atualmente);
                $sql->bindValue(":tr", $telefone);
                $sql->bindValue(":cl", $celular);
                $sql->bindValue(":tc", $telefone_comercial);
                $sql->bindValue(":hp", $homepage);
                $sql->bindValue(":na", $nacionalidade);
                $sql->bindValue(":cp", $cep);
                $sql->bindValue(":en", $endereço);
                $sql->bindValue(":nc", $num_casa);
                $sql->bindValue(":cm", $complemento);
                $sql->bindValue(":br", $bairro);
                $sql->bindValue(":et", $estado);
                $sql->bindValue(":ct", $cidade);
                $sql->bindValue(":se", $senha);
                $sql->execute();
                return true;

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Ola @user151382, Bem vindo ao SOpt, antes de começar de uma olhada em nosso [Tour]. Sobre sua pergunta você precisa informar que erro esta acontecendo. =D

Answer (score 0):

Segue umas correções que eu fiz e testa para confirmar se testa por favor!

```
class User{

    private $pdo; //privado para usar somente nessa class
    public $msg; //publico para usar em qualquer lugar

    public function conect($name, $host, $user, $password)
    {
        try 
        {
            //Quando você declara variáveis private ou public não precisa declarar em Global, só passar um $this->nomevar;
            $this->pdo= new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$name.";host=".$host,$user, $password);
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
            $msgError = $e->getMessage();
        }


    }

    public function register($nome, $email, $sexo, $estado_civil, $data_nascimento, $empregado_atualmente,
     $telefone, $celular, $telefone_comercial, $homepage, $nacionalidade, $cep, $endereço, $num_casa, $complemento, $bairro, $estado, $cidade)
    {

        //Verificar se o email já existe
        $sql=$tihs->pdo->prepare("SELECT id_usuario FROM dados_pessoais WHERE email = :e");
        $sql->bindValue(":e", $email);
        $sql->execute();

        if($sql->rowsCount() > 0){
            return false; //email já cadastrado
        }
        else
        {
            //caso o email estiver cadastrado todos os dados serão salvos
            $sql=$this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO dados_pessoais (nome, email, sexo, estado_civil, data_nascimento, empregado_atualmente, telefone, celular, telefone_comercial, homepage, nacionalidade, cep, endereço, num_casa, complemento, bairro, estado, cidade, senha,) VALUES (NULL,:n, :e, :sx, :ec, :dn, :ea, :tr, :cl, :tc, :hp, :na, :cp, :en, :nc, :cm, :br, :et, :ct, :se)");
            $sql->bindValue(":n", $nome);
            $sql->bindValue(":e", $email);
            $sql->bindValue(":sx", $sexo);
            $sql->bindValue(":ec", $estado_civil);
            $sql->bindValue(":dn", $data_nascimento);
            $sql->bindValue(":ea", $empregado_atualmente);
            $sql->bindValue(":tr", $telefone);
            $sql->bindValue(":cl", $celular);
            $sql->bindValue(":tc", $telefone_comercial);
            $sql->bindValue(":hp", $homepage);
            $sql->bindValue(":na", $nacionalidade);
            $sql->bindValue(":cp", $cep);
            $sql->bindValue(":en", $endereço);
            $sql->bindValue(":nc", $num_casa);
            $sql->bindValue(":cm", $complemento);
            $sql->bindValue(":br", $bairro);
            $sql->bindValue(":et", $estado);
            $sql->bindValue(":ct", $cidade);
            $sql->bindValue(":se", $senha);
            $sql->execute();
            return true;

        }
    }

}
```